# Eclipse eye for a Visual Studio guy

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, eclipse

trying to do some Android development, which means Eclipse, however, most of my experience is Microsoft tools (*e.g. Visual Studio*).  My java experience is mostly either Blackberry dev in the *JDE* and some miscellaneous stuff back in the *Java 1.0* days.

My question is this.  In VS200x, there is a `.sln` (solution), `.csproj`(project), etc...
What are the equivalent file extensions for Eclipse?  Do they even exist?  I am having trouble with the basics, like how does one load a project into a **workspace**.

- Is there a tutorial for Microsoft refugees somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use file import and then choose Existing projects into workspace.
A .project file and a .classpath file will be created.

I find the Eclipse way of working to be incredibly frustrating having come from Delphi/JBuilder where a single project file held all your settings.

Make sure that you back up your workspace as well - there is nothing worse than recreating it when you are under pressure!

Comment: Agreed. Eclipse can be such a frustrating IDE to work in. It also freezes very often on my system and I have to wait like 20 seconds. I find it to be very bloated.

Comment: I have started looking at Netbeans - faster IDE, better multi-language support, built in profiler etc. I have never got the Eclipse profile stuff working on anything other than a toy project. I wonder whether the Android stuff would work well in Netbeans?

Comment: Your suggestion has actually solved my issue.  Thanks.  My frustration was with the fact that i couldn't find a way to load the Android sample projects into the IDE.  Your suggestion was right on the money, since Android does not ship Eclipse projects, rather just source that needs to be imported.

Comment: Happy to have helped - I keep meaning to take a look at the Android stuff myself but haven't found the time yet.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-visualstudio/?ca=dgr-lnxw06Eclipse-VS) for "An introduction to Eclipse for Visual Studio users"...

Basically, for Java program (I never done any Android development) the basic Eclipse configuration files for a project are a .classpath (defining the dependencies of your project), and a .project file, that contains all specificities to your project configuration. In addition to that, a .settings directory is created, which contains some configuration files for plugins activated on your project.

Edit:

Eclipse is the most used IDE for the Java development. However, the **best** IDE is [JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). I see that there is a plugin for it to develop Android applications ([here](http://code.google.com/p/idea-android/)). If you can affort this wonderful application ($249), you will not regret it! You may eventually try the free 30 days trial...

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents :

Make sure to version control your .project and .classpath. You may aslo want to use path variables to reference directory where the external dependencies (third parties libs) are located.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing it for fun or for commercial purposes? Because if money is involved, if I were you, I would really consider investing in [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), which is arguably the best IDE Java IDE out there, but unfortunately it is not exactly free. The Android SDK has some support for IntelliJ out of the box so it's not like you had to write all the makefiles yourself manually. If you liked Visual Studio, you would like IntelliJ, so why don't you download the trial version and have a look at it.

Just my 2 cents.